# Simple iOS camera

Tags: ios

I am creating a simple iOS camera app using the code snippet from apple

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = <#Get a capture session#>;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
UIView *aView = <#The view in which to present the layer#>;
previewLayer.frame = aView.bounds; // Assume you want the preview layer to fill the view.
[aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

But when I run the app on my device all I get is a white square, all the UI is in the right place,  I don't know whats wrong.

.m code

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *lagSquare;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *help;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *start;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureSession *session;
    @end
```

.h code

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
_start.layer.borderWidth = 2;
_start.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
_start.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
_help.layer.borderWidth = 2;
_help.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
_help.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
// Setup camera preview image
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = _session;
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
UIView *aView = _lagSquare;
previewLayer.frame = aView.bounds; // Assume you want the preview layer to fill the view.
[aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
}

- (IBAction)start:(id)sender {
//write main code

}

- (IBAction)help:(id)sender {
// go to help page
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
} 

@end
```

Comment: Why don't you take a look at sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start running the session for getting the camera view. You can use the following code for that.

```
[session startRunning];
```

Comment: Before allocating AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

Comment: [session startRunning]; give me an error to put [_session startRunning]; I replaced it and pushed to my device and i still get a white square

Comment: Please check this one: https://github.com/cokecoffe/ios-demo/blob/master/capturepause/CapturePause/CameraEngine.m